# When I try to add ActionListener to a button, I cant,

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

When I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:CastleDefenders [line: 45] - CastleDefenders()
    - The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable 
     for the arguments (CastleDefenders)
```

Code:

```
public CastleDefenders(){
    button = new JButton("Go!");
    lvl1.setToolTipText("Play the game on Easy");
    lvl2.setToolTipText("Play the game on Normal");
    lvl3.setToolTipText("Play the game on Hard");
    lvl1.setActionCommand("Easy");
    lvl2.setActionCommand("Normal");
    lvl3.setActionCommand("Hard");
    lvls.add(lvl1);
    lvls.add(lvl2);
    lvls.add(lvl3);
    pnl2.add(lvl1);
    pnl2.add(lvl2);
    pnl2.add(lvl3);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    tlkt = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    pnl2.setBounds(50, 5, 1, 10);
    btn.setBounds(220, 240, 5, 1);
    f.setJMenuBar(mb2);
    g.setJMenuBar(mb2);
    mnuFile.add(mnuItemQuit);
    mnuHelp.add(mnuItemAbout);
    mb.add(mnuFile);
    mb.add(mnuHelp);
    mb2.add(mnuFile);
    mb2.add(mnuHelp);
    pnl.add(btn);
    pnl2.add(lbl);
    pnl2.add(button);
    lbl.setBounds(0, 240, 10, 2);
    lbl.setEditable(false);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.getContentPane().add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
    f.addWindowListener(new ListenCloseWdw());
    g.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    g.getContentPane().add(pnl2);   
    g.addWindowListener(new ListenCloseWdw());
    mnuItemAbout.addActionListener(new GetAboutInfo());     
    btn.addActionListener(new GetButtonClick());    
    mnuItemQuit.addActionListener(new ListenMenuQuit());
    add(button);


}
```

Comment: Does your class CastleDefenders implement ActionListener?

Comment: FWIW: you should never call setBounds/setSize/setLocation on any components. Leave all this to the LayoutManager's. Don't be tempted by using null-layout nor to use setPreferredSize.

Answer (score 0):

You need your `CastleDefenders` class to implement the [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface if you want it to listen to action events.  From the error message it appears that you haven't done that yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:
button.addActionListener(this);
What's the type of CastleDefenders? Does CastleDefenders implements ActionListener?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer